# React.js Login Page Not Sending to Profile Page

Tags: python, reactjs, authentication, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Im trying to make a login page and It doesent send the user to the profile page when I log in. This is the guide I was trying to follow: https://dev.to/oyedeletemitope/login-authentication-with-react-and-fastapi-397b  .

My Login Code

```
import React from 'react'
import {  useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchToken, setToken } from './Auth'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
function Login() {
  
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [usernamelog,setUsernamelog]=useState('');
    const [passwordlog,setPasswordlog]=useState('');
    
    const [loginStatus,setLoginStatus]=useState('')
    
    const login=()=>{
      console.log('login clicked')
      
      if ((usernamelog == "") & (passwordlog == "")) {
        return;
      } else {
      
      axios.post('http://localhost:4060/login',{
         
      
          username:usernamelog,
          password:passwordlog,
          
        }).then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data.token, "response.data.token");
          if (response.data.token) {
            setToken(response.data.token);
            navigate("/profile");
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error, "error");
        });

       }
      };
  
    return (
    <div className='Login' >
          <h2>Login</h2>
         
          <div >
          {fetchToken() ? (
            <p>you are logged in</p>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <form>
                <label >Input Username</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setUsernamelog(e.target.value)}
                />

                <label >Input Password</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setPasswordlog(e.target.value)}
                />

                <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

     </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

My Authentication Code

```
import { useLocation,Navigate } from "react-router-dom"

export const setToken = (token)=>{

    localStorage.setItem('temitope', token)// make up your own token
}

export const fetchToken = (token)=>{

    return localStorage.getItem('temitope')
}

export function RequireToken({children}){

    let auth = fetchToken()
    let location = useLocation()

    if(!auth){

        return <Navigate to='/' state ={{from : location}}/>;
    }

    return children;
}
export default fetchToken
```

My Profile Code

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
export default function Profile() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const signOut = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("temitope");
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20, minHeight: 700 }}>
        <h1>Profile page</h1>
        <p>Hello there, welcome to your profile page</p>

        <button onClick={signOut}>sign out</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

my main app code

```
import './App.css';

import * as yup from "yup";
import {userSchema} from './Validations/UserValid'
import { RequireToken } from "./components/Auth";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home'; 
import Login from './components/login';
import Register from './components/register';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
function App() {
 
  
  

  const createUser= async (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData ={
    firstname: event.target[0]?.value,
    lastname: event.target[1]?.value,
    organization: event.target[2]?.value,
    email: event.target[3]?.value,
    password: event.target[4]?.value,
    };
    const isValid= await userSchema.isValid(formData);
    console.log(isValid);

  };

 
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Our Future Reads</h1>
          
        <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path ="/" element={<Home />}/>
          <Route path ="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route
  path="/profile"
  element={
    <RequireToken>
      <Profile />
    </RequireToken>
  }
/>
         
        </Routes>
        
      </Router>
          
          
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my relevant backend code

```
router= APIRouter(tags=["Authentication"])

@router.post('/login')
def login(request:OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(database.get_db) ):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == request.username).first()
    if not user:
         raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail= f"Invalid Credentials")

    if not Hash.verify(user.password, request.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail= f"Invalid password" )   
    
    
    access_token = token.create_access_token(data={"sub": user.email})
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong. I dont seem to be getting any errors and I had a little trouble understanding the guide during the authentication part. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'd be happy to add more info if anyone needs it.

Comment: try adding some log statements... see if you are even getting in that case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check

1. If the login function is working
2. If the api calling is working
3. If the data sending is correct and in correct format
4. If the response is as expected
5. this condition is working :

   if (response.data.token) {
   setToken(response.data.token);
   navigate("/profile");
   }
6. useNavigate is working.

try solving step by step, we could solve this issue.